# How to find what .NET method led caused the worker to stop

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

My code has deadlocked. Here is the stack trace for the main thread:

> [Managed to Native Transition]
>
> > WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.GetMessageW(ref System.Windows.Interop.MSG msg,
> >     System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef hWnd, int uMsgFilterMin, int
> >     uMsgFilterMax) + 0x14 bytes
> >       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.GetMessage(ref
> >     System.Windows.Interop.MSG msg, System.IntPtr hwnd, int minMessage,
> >     int maxMessage) + 0x80 bytes
> >       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame
> >     frame) + 0x75 bytes
> >       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame
> >     frame) + 0x49 bytes
> >       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run() + 0x4b
> >     bytes
> >       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(object
> >     ignore) + 0x17 bytes
> >       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window
> >     window) + 0x6f bytes
> >       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window
> >     window) + 0x26 bytes
> >       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.Run() + 0x1b
> >     bytes     MainDashboard.exe!MainDashboard.App.Main() + 0x59 bytes C# 
> >       [Native to Managed Transition]      [Managed to Native Transition]
> >       mscorlib.dll!System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(string assemblyFile,
> >     System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, string[] args) +
> >     0x6b bytes
> >       Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
> >     + 0x27 bytes      mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(object
> >     state) + 0x6f bytes
> >       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
> >     executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
> >     state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0xa7 bytes
> >       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
> >     executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
> >     state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0x16 bytes
> >       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
> >     executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
> >     state) + 0x41 bytes
> >       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() + 0x44
> >     bytes     [Native to Managed Transition]

How do I know what part of my code is responsible.  The application entry point is:

> MainDashboard.exe!MainDashboard.App.Main() + 0x59 bytes C#

and that is the only line in this stacktrace that is from my code.

Trying to view the call stack for two other frames displays the following:

> The current thread is not currently running code all the call stack is
>   could not be obtained.

Here is the call stack of another worker thread:

> [Managed to Native Transition]
>
> > System.dll!Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.WindowThreadProc() + 0xaf bytes
> >       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(object
> >     state) + 0x6f bytes
> >       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
> >     executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
> >     state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0xa7 bytes
> >       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
> >     executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
> >     state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0x16 bytes
> >       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
> >     executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
> >     state) + 0x41 bytes
> >       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() + 0x44
> >     bytes     [Native to Managed Transition]

And here is the call stack of the last thread:

> [Managed to Native Transition]
>
> > Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.WaitForThreadExit()
> >     + 0x93 bytes      Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunParkingWindowThread()
> >     + 0x253 bytes     mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(object
> >     state) + 0x6f bytes
> >       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
> >     executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
> >     state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0xa7 bytes
> >       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
> >     executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
> >     state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0x16 bytes
> >       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
> >     executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
> >     state) + 0x41 bytes
> >       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() + 0x44
> >     bytes     [Native to Managed Transition]

The app is hanged. there is a total of 49,000 records it needs to process. it stopped at 3,029. The app is not using any resources at this point. Task Manager is showing it using 0% CPU. The UI is responsive, but it is designed to be always responsive.

Also, this is not deterministic. I mean, if I restart the app, it will hang at a different point in the code, so there is not one record that has an issue that brings the whole thing down.

Comment: How does stack trace look for the other threads?

Comment: Some versions of Visual Studio have a concurrency visualizer which should be able to do what you want.

Comment: @kkokosa, I edited the question with the other call stacks.

Comment: No evidence for deadlock at all, everything looks normal.

Comment: @HansPassant, so where is it stopped? I know there is no info there for you to answer that, but why has the app stopped? What could the cause of something like that be? Or how would I go about trying to find out.

Comment: When you say that it's deadlocked, what do you mean? Is the UI not responding? Are the threads that should be doing something not doing anything? Does Task Manager show that your app is using 0% CPU?

Comment: @JimMischel, the app is hanged. there is a total of 49,000 records it needs to process. it stopped at 3,029. The app is not using any resources at this point. Task Manager is indeed showing it using 0% CPU. The UI is responsive, but it is designed to be always responsive.

Comment: The fact that the processing has stopped does not mean that there's any deadlock. It may be something as simple as yours main-processing loop getting `break`ed improperly or some exception was thrown and some outer `try/catch` has jumped out of your main-processing loop and hence halted the process. If you had the debugger attached, check the Output for any `first-chance exception` notifications. Any NullReference, ArgumentOutOfRange, NotImplemented, InvalidOperation etc may be a sign of a bad errorhandling that simply halted your loop.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl, you are absolutely right. Output says that a bunch of First Chance exceptions have been thrown and a bunch of threads have exited right after the first chance exceptions. How do I debug this further. The output does not have line numbers or any way to see what the exception was. Thanks!

Comment: So your worker threads are supposed to be processing items, but they aren't. Are they waiting on a concurrent queue of some type? Are you using synchronization primitives (locks, semaphores, events, etc.) to control access to shared state? That's the place to look.

Comment: How about putting `try ... catch` in your threads and have them log the exceptions?

Comment: @JimMischel, thanks, I added a couple of try catches towards the entry point of the application. Thee should grab any exceptions that are not handled, running again, lets see what I will catch :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you now noticed 'first chance exceptions' in your 'Output' and they seem to kill your threads, there's one more thing other than just try/catch/log.

Use the debugging features of VS/CLR even further. Go to DEBUG menu, then EXCEPTIONS then find one (or all, but I prefer to do it one-by-one) of the exceptions you identified as thrown-and-killing-your-threads, i.e. InvalidOperationException and check the tick "thrown" or "unhandled" (depending on what you want and what version of VS you have).

Now, assuming you ticked "thrown", the IDE will **automatically break/halt** the program whenever it tried to throw exactly this one type of exception.

..and not only it will halt the program, it will also jump there as if you placed a breakpoint. You'll instantly get all the stacktraces, variables, code, etc you'd like to inspect.

But, on the other hand, if you app is spamming with this kind of exception with rate of thousands per second, just because someone was lazy and if/else'd some bad-arguments case and try/caught the exception instead, then trying to rely on this exception being "thrown" will .. well.. fail. In such case, you might want to try with "unhandled" tick instead (if you see it in the IDE at all), but of course it has its own limitations, too. Nevertheless, they are really precious tools if only you can attach the IDE to the failing process. Insta-break on the unknown line with problems!